# VMware Tool up to date or not via commandline (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, vmware, powershell-3.0, vmware-tools

I have been trying to automate Windows server build QA in my company. One of the tasks is to make sure vmware tools is up to date or not. Servers are built off of templates which may not be up to date.

Obviously I thought of getting the vmware tool version on the new build and comparing it with a standard build number to determine uptodateness. But that leaves little room for flexibility.

Now, if the vmtools are not upto date, the server shows a notification in the tray. So I am looking for a way to obtain that result remotely through commandline(I am open to using psexec). Am I asking for the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can download all VMWare Tools manually [Here](https://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/index.html)
Write a program to compare the file size of online and offline files 
and update it if they are outdated.

Schedule the Program as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using right now. Getting the installed version and comparing with the current version number. It is not the best way but it works for me.

```
$VMtoolVersion = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $FQDN -Credential $PSCredential -ScriptBlock { & 'C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\VMwareToolboxCmd.exe' -v} -ErrorAction Stop
if($VMtoolVersion -match "9.4.15.48277")
            {
                Write-Host "`tUPTO DATE" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "`tOUT OF DATE. Please Update VMWare Tools " -ForegroundColor Red
            }
```

Problem is when the tool version is higher than 9.4.15.48277, it is still gonna give me "Outdated" message. So the script will need to be updated as tools get updated.